# Выборка по дате в mysql

Tags: дата, php, mysql

В таблице (с новостями, ага) есть поле с типом datetime.
Вот сейчас загнал туда 30 записей, и хочу вывести все записи от 13 мая и старше.
Делаю такой запрос:

```
SELECT 
        news.id_news,
        news.id_rubric,
        DATE_FORMAT(news.\`date\`, '%e %M %Y') as \`date\`,
        DATE_FORMAT(news.\`date\`, '%H:%i') as \`time\`,
        news.title, news.\`text\`
FROM news 
WHERE news.\`date\` >=  '17-05-2012' ORDER BY news.\`date\` DESC
```

И выводятся все записи вне зависимости от моих просьб mysql'ю (: Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно составить запрос?

Comment: от 13 мая - '17-05-2012'

кэп

Comment: WUT? .....

Answer (score 1):

Формат даты в моем запросе не верный.
Надо: 2012-05-13